# Installshield and Redistributables

Tags: installation, installshield, redistributable

I have .net 3.5 application

I have made basic MSI installer with `installshield` added .net 3.5 in `Redistributables` tab rebuild and checked .`msi` and .`exe` but size is same .net only added in `ISSetupPrerequisites` folder

Installshield does not put `Redistributables` in .msi?

I must send full folder (DiskImages) to my clients?

Answer (score 1):

their would be no points in putting the redistribuable in the MSI since you cannot launch another msi while an msi is runing.

a good practice would be to compressed all your files in the setup.exe. it's easier to carry around and prevent anyone from replacing them with nasty stuff and launch them with admin's right.
[right click on the prerequisit and open the properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfpCp.png)

Now specificly for the .net 3.5, since it's a windows feature on most of the modern OS (anything but xp...) the installation of the module will failed. I would suggest making a launch condition validation the presence of the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5|Version`. [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty8Su.png)

it will make your installer smaller and probably more usefull since you can customize the error message to explain how to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress everything into the .exe file (select compressed, and "extract from setup.exe" as appropriate), but since Windows Installer does not handle prerequisites, it cannot be just the .msi file.

If you stick to the uncompressed build you described, then yes, you must send the full contents of at least the Disk1 folder (also any other Disk folders if there are any; they're typically only used for multiple-disk media scenarios).